# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using ANTLR, JavaCC or JFlex over StringTokenizer and equivalents?

Tags: java, performance, parsing, lexer, lexical-analysis

I am currently looking at implementing the language shown [here](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2012/GDC2012_Ruskin_Elan_DynamicDialog.pdf) in Java. The presentation is a little long, but it is essentially a DSL for creating dynamic speech. 
Example:

```
rule ExampleRule
{
    criteria Criterion1 Criterion2 Criterion3=value
    response ExampleResponse
    remember State:=1
    trigger Object TriggerName
    ApplyFacts "State1:1:0,State2:1:0"
}
response ExampleResponse
{
    say "Text" then object ExampleRule
    say "Text" then any ExampleRule
    say "Text"
    scene "Scenepath"
}
```

I have looked at the different parser generators such as ANTLR, JavaCC and JFlex, but am wondering whether to just use StringTokenizer/Scanner and roll my own parser, as it is for a hobby project.

I had earlier decided on ANTLR but ran into some issues with ANTLR using full pathnames in the generated source code, and the runtime library seemed a bit heavyweight. I have not been able to find much information comparing the three parser libraries or the inbuilt Java alternatives.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each parser given the nature of the language?

Comment: It all depends on how complex your language is. Without details (i.e. a grammar for the language) this question is dangerously close to "not constructive" territory as it asks for opinions/discussion.  I suggest you include a grammar or detailed description of the language.

Comment: Added a link to a description of the language.

Comment: TL;DR but _you're going to need a bigger parser-generator_ :-)

Comment: Added an example syntax.

Comment: Definitely go with a parser generator. This will force you to define a formal grammar, and will be much easier to change in future.

Comment: Need to decide on which to use then... as the question says, I had a few niggles with ANTLR.

Comment: _That_ question is definitely "not constructive". Nobody can decide for you, you will have to try one or two yourself and make your own decision.  After you've tried one, if you have a particular _specific_ question about a problem you run into, ask another question here.  Most of the available tools have support forums, which will be more amenable to this type of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantages of using parser generators:

1. Correctness by construction. The generated parser accepts exactly the language specified in the grammar, and there are all kinds of CS proofs of that for the various kinds of generators, starting with [Knuth 1965](http://classes.engr.oregonstate.edu/eecs/winter2012/cs480/assignments/Knuth-1965-TranslationofLanguages.pdf). If you roll your own, e.g. recursive descent, you have no immediate proof of that, and no easy way to test it.
2. Development time. Once you get your head around the generator's foibles, the parser is built about as fast as you can type.

'Given the nature of the language' isn't all that relevant. Major practitioners made major mistakes in implementing nothing more complex than arithmetic expressions in the 1960s, which is why my point (1) is my point (1).

Comment: Can you please give a little bit more information with regard to the language I'm looking to implement?

Comment: Assuming you do it twice to begin with.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Not really. I used 'yacc' for a long series of one-off processors for custom languages in the 1990s and I didn't even contemplate RD or any other hand-rolled technique for any of them. If I had done that I doubt that any of them would ever have got finished. Note that I am not saying here that there are no disadvantages. Prior to that I had spent several years with a production RD compiler for COBOL and I would probably not want to do that again.

Comment: EJP: for every such statement, you get one from the opposite site too, so you feeling that way doesn't change the point.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort These are not 'feelings'. These are the findings from  empirical experience from someone who practiced the trade for over twenty years. I don't know what 'assuming you did it twice' even means, unless you're allowing some weight to experience, which is one of the two things I'm purveying nhere. You've completely overlooked the other one.

Comment: @fullwall The language you're looking to implement isn't all that relevance. Both my points stand over a caseload of over twenty languages implemented.

Comment: EJP: I assume that doing it twice simply meant that there is a difference between the time learning a compiler-compiler and associated tools in and out AND doing a new language with it (that you have to formally nail first, like in our case with Delphi), or the time for doing it the umpteenth time starting with a production-ready grammar that falls into your lap. If you make general statements, mention your border conditions and assumptions.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort That is a counsel of perfection, and I don't see you mentioning any boundary conditions or assumptions anywhere: in your own answer for example. The OP is asking for advice and I am purveying it, based on what is now 45 years of experience, and both of the numbered points I stated are facts. Not 'feelings'. Your point escapes me completely.

Answer (score 0):

There're four [types of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) that require appropriate automation (recognition) mechanism. StringTokenizer and Scanner are suitable for a regular language (the simplest of all), but for a context-free language (e.g. programming languages, XML and other languages that contain nested structures) more advanced mechanisms are required (e.g. pushdown automata).

Without a very detailed look, it seems that in your case you'd be better off with tools such as ANTLR. They do require learning, but far less than to learn how to create you own lexer and parser for a context-free language.

Answer (score -1):

Generally this depends on the crowd you ask.

If you talk to compiler people that maintain a **single** compiler, suffer from *backwards compatibility* requirements (with previous versions or other dialects (-options) unified in one parser), have requirements on parsing speeds etc, you generally want recursive descent (most production compilers are RD).

If you talk (also professional) compiler people that **routinely** produce C or C++ compilers customized for yet another vendor's silicon, the arguments are more like EJP's. Of course they generally take a C(++) standard grammar they already have, and add some architecture customized constructs.